# For two p.d. matrices $A$ and $B$, prove that $\lambda_1(AB)\leqslant \lambda_1(A) \cdot\lambda_1(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ and $B$ are two nxn positive definite matrices, then show that

$$\lambda_1(AB) \leqslant \lambda_1(A) \cdot \lambda_1(B),$$

where $\lambda_1(\cdot)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a positive symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, and let $|\cdot|$ be the standard euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$. For all $X\in\Bbb R^n$,
$$|CX|\leq\lambda_1(C)|X|$$
with equality *iff* $X$ is eigenvector of $C$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1(C)$, so that, again, for $C$ positive symmetric,
$$\lambda_1(C)=\max_{|X|\leq 1}|CX|=\|C\|$$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the matrix norm subordinate to the standard euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$.
The answer to your question now follows, as for any matrix $D$ and any eigenvalue $\lambda$,  $|\lambda|\leq \|D\|$ so that
$$|\lambda_1(AB)|\leq\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\cdot\|B\|=\lambda_1(A)\lambda_1(B)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

$AB$ is similar to an SPD matrix, hence they have same eigenvalues:
$$
AB\sim B^{1/2}(AB)B^{-1/2}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\lambda_{1}(AB)=\lambda_1(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}).
$$
Using this and the variational characterisation of $\lambda_1$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\lambda_1(AB)&=\max_x\frac{x^TB^{1/2}AB^{1/2}x}{x^Tx}
=\max_y\frac{y^TAy}{y^TB^{-1}y}
=\max_y\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}\frac{y^Ty}{y^TB^{-1}y}\\
&\leq\max_y\left(\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}\right)\left(\max_y\frac{y^Ty}{y^TB^{-1}y}\right)
=\left(\max_y\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}\right)\left(\max_z\frac{z^TBz}{z^Tz}\right)
=\lambda_1(A)\lambda_1(B).
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score -1):

Let the eigen values of $AB$ be $c_1, c_2, \ldots,c_n$ and those of $A$ and $B$ be $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$ respectively.
Now, we know that, $\det(A)$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $A$, counted with their algebraic multiplicities.

Also, we have, $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$

$$
\Rightarrow c_1 c_2 \cdots c_n = (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n)(b_1 b_2 \cdots b_n)
$$

=> $c_1$ * $c_2$ * ... * $c_n$ = ($a_1$ * $a_2$ * ... * $a_n$) * ($b_1$ * $b_2$ * ... * $b_n$ )

Using the above equality/identity(since all eigenvalues are positive, $A$ & $B$ being p.d.), we can evidently write:

$$\lambda_1(AB) \le \lambda_1(A) \lambda_1(B).$$

Comment: I don't get it. You post a question and straight away (incorrectly) answer it?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, Why do you think my answer is incorrect? I have given valid reasoning.

Comment: @A.Chakraborty Merely that all eigenvalues of $A,B,AB$ are positive is not enough to guarantee that $\lambda_1(AB)\le\lambda(A)\lambda(B)$. For example, consider $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1}$ and $B=A^T$. The eigenvalues of $AB=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&2}$ are $\frac12(3\pm\sqrt{5})=2.618,\, 0.382$. Note that $A$ and $B$ are *not* Hermitian in this example, and the Hermitian-ness of $A$ and $B$ is crucial in this question, but you haven't made use of it.